# Requests останавливает скрипт

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests

Я пишу api функцию для получения комментариев из задания, но почему то запрос начал обрывать выполнение кода.

Код:

```
    def comments(self, task_id):
        task = response(f'http://***********/api.php?key=*******&cat=task&action=show&id={task_id}')['data']
        comments = {}

        try:
            print(task['comments'])
            for comment in task['comments']:
                print(1)
                comment = task['comments'][comment]
                print(2)
                author = response(f'http://***********/api.php?key=*******&cat=employee&action=get_data&id={comment["employee_id"]}')['data'][0]
                print(3)
                comments[comment['comment']] = author['name']
                print(4)
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return comments
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
{'5380': {'id': 5380, 'employee_id': 184, 'comment': '56456456'}, '5379': {'id': 5379, 'employee_id': 184, 'comment': 'wewfwefwqfq'}}
1
2
```

Образ API:
cat=task&action=show&id=id:

```
{
    "data": {
        [id]: {
            "id": [id],
            "name": [name],
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

cat=employee&action=get_data&id=id:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": [id],
        "comments": {
            [id]: {
                "id": [id],
                "employee_id": [author],
                "comment": [comment]
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Если вручную перейти на сайт, то все работает
*ключ api и сайт я скрыл  на "*"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выполняете свой код в блоке try, однако не предусматриваете обработку исключений. Я предполагаю, что после выполнения второго этапа у вас возникает исключение. Рекомендую переписать ваш код без использования конструкции try, либо поделитесь информацией об ошибке, которая возникает у вас. Возможно, также стоит учесть возможное исключение IndexError.

Comment: У меня стоит try для отлавливания KeyError, ведь не у всех заданий есть комментарии.

Comment: Тогда вам следует вынести код после второго этапа из блока try и отловить ошибку которая у вас вызникает, будет хорошо если поделитесь ей, сам запрос не останавливет выполнение кода

Comment: Я убрал try полностью и проблема решилась. Оказалось, что из словарей нельзя брать данные по определенном индексу... (`response(f'http://testus.neotelecom.kg/api.php?key=aspergilus&cat=employee&action=get_data&id={comment["employee_id"]}')['data'][0]`)

Comment: А так у вас там словарь был, даже внимания не обратил